# fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean

Tags: git, version-control

When I am trying to clean all untracked files by `git clean` it shows me the error:

```
fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: PHPStorm has a wonderful feature built into it - in the Local Changes tab you can click 'browse' to see a list of local files. You can just hit ctrl + a, delete and enter - job done!

Comment: @ClarkyBoy almost all popular UI basee git clients have such kindof feature but internally they do something similar.

Comment: Yes but what I mean is that there is no need to do `git clean` - just select all files and hit delete to get rid of all local files. I had 4k yesterday after updating 3 plugins in WordPress. Updating from the repo would update those which were already in git but wouldn't touch those which were only on my machine. This was an easy way to clean up all that mess, that's all I'm saying :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to either set `requireForce` to `false` in  your `.gitconfig` or use the `-f` or `-i` flag with this command.

1. `git clean -f` will force to clean the untracked files even if `clean.requireForce` is set to true which is default.
2. `git clean -i` will give you an interactive way for cleaning each file
3. `git clean -n` will just show which files will be removed if you perform git clean.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: `git clean -i` and `git clean -n` just return instantly with no actions or stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to `false` by running this command `git config --local clean.requireForce false`.

You can also change the `--local` flag to `--global` to set it in global git config, that will apply to all future repos that you initialise.